# I can't win against my rival

Tags: asphalt-8

Whenever I race against  my rival, I can't win because I can't knock him down it's like he's invisible or maybe he teleports. I have tried perfect nitros but I can't win him. What should I do? (Asphalt-8-Airborne)

Answer (score 0):

If a player is blinking/teleporting, it may be because either your device or their device has poor internet connectivity. Check your internet, then try another race. Note that it will be significantly easier to win with a lower class car than with a higher class car as you'll consistently be near top speed.

Source: personal experience - I have won multiple races with this "issue" present